# c# - DataTable expression column using linq

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I need to add columns from one datatable to another only if the columns in second datable not exists and also the second datatable has expression column that needs to set value from first datatable column using linq.

I have achieved this using foreach but how to do without foreach in linq ?

```
        DataTable first = new DataTable();
        first.Clear();
        first.Columns.Add("Name");
        first.Columns.Add("Exp");
        DataRow _ra = dt1.NewRow();
        _ra["Name"] = "Column_1";
        _ra["Exp"] = "ExpTarget * Column_3";
        first.Rows.Add(_ra);
        DataRow _r = dt1.NewRow();
        _r["Name"] = "Column_2";
        _r["Exp"] = "ExpTarget * Column_3";
        first.Rows.Add(_r);
        DataRow _r2 = dt1.NewRow();
        _r2["Name"] = "Column_3";
        _r2["Exp"] = "ExpTarget";
        first.Rows.Add(_r2);


        DataTable second = new DataTable();
        second.Clear();
        second.Columns.Add("Column_3",typeof(System.Int16));
        second.Columns.Add("ExpTarget",typeof(System.Int16));
        DataRow _r21 = table.NewRow();
        _r21["Column_3"] = 100;
        _r21["ExpTarget"] = 2;
        second.Rows.Add(_r21);
```

Code to add columns & expression is below, i need to avoid **foreach** linq below for expression column, how to do it without foreach ?

```
   // get all columns from first datatable
   string[] col = string.Join(",", first.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Name"].ToString()).ToArray()).Split(',').ToArray();

   // get all columns and expression from first datatable
   List<string> exp = string.Join(",", first.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Name"].ToString() + "~" + x["Exp"].ToString()).ToArray()).Split(',').ToList();

   List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
   list.Add(col);

   second.Columns.AddRange(list.First().Select(r => second.Columns.Contains(r) ? second.Columns["Dummy"] : new DataColumn(r, typeof(System.Decimal))).ToArray());

   exp.ForEach(r =>  
   {
       second.Columns[r.ToString().Split('~')[0].ToString()].Expression = r.ToString().Split('~')[1].ToString();

    });
```

Comment: Using cast works nicely : string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Comment: That 'ForEach` isn't LINQ - it is a method on `List`s.

Comment: Using `String.Join` and `Split` and `ToArray` and `ToList` in a single expression is extremely questionable. Note that `String.Join(x,...).Split(x)` does __nothing__.

Comment: Also using `string` and separators to combine objects is a very bad idea and ignores most C# features for properly accomplishing the same thing.